# Problema con precisión con Double - Java

Tags: java, double

---

Hola, buenas noches. Tengo un problema que no he podido resolver por más que he buscado. Tengo dos variables double en Java (estoy trabajando con números muy grandes) el problema es cuando a un número demasiado grande le sumo uno pequeño, tengo esto

```
double test1= 100000000000000000000.0;

double test2=test1+1.0;

System.out.println(test2);
```

También he intentado esto:

```
double test1= 100000000000000000000;

double test2=test1+1;

System.out.println(test2);
```

El problema es que el output es el siguiente:

```
100000000000000000000
```

O sea, no le suma los números pequeños, da igual si le sumo 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 simplemente no los agrega. Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto?Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hay una pregunta sobre problemas de presicion en el sitio. La verificaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que la solución es no usar Double.
Para el calculo que estas haciendo puedes usar BigDecimal. Si Double no puede resolver todos los problemas. Cuando se quiere mayor precisión o cuando los números son muy grandes es mejor usar BigDecimal.

```
BigDecimal test1= new BigDecimal(100000000000000000000.0);

// la linea de abajo también pudo escribirse como el código que comento
// BigDecimal test2= test1.add( BigDecimal.ONE);
BigDecimal test2= test1.add( new BigDecimal(1.0));

System.out.println(test2);
```

Quedo atento a cualquier comentario

Comment: Muchas gracias, investigué un poco más de BigDecimal(el cual ya había probado pero por alguna razón no me había convencido) y ahora pude hacer funcionar de buena manera mi código. Saludos!

Comment: Que bueno que te ayudo. Saludos cordiales